# How To get index row and column in array 2D php

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, multidimensional-array, cakephp-2.0

I have an array of data like this . This array is the result of a database query , I want to get the index of rows and columns . I tried to get the index of each row but nonetheless failed. so, can anyone help me?

**Query Result**

```
array(
(int) 0 => array( 
            'B' => array(
                        'company' => 'ABC' 
            ), 
            'User' => array( 
                        'company' => 'abc' 
            ), 
            (int) 0 => array(
                            'date_part' => '3',
                            'jumlah' => null, 
                            'jumbuy' => '50990', 
                            'admin' => '50010' 
            ),
            (int) 1 => array(
                            'date_part' => '4',
                            'jumlah' => null, 
                            'jumbuy' => '98990', 
                            'admin' => '2010' 
            )
),
(int) 1 => array(
            'B' => array( 
                        'company' => 'BCD'
            ), 
            'User' => array( 
                            'company' => 'bcd' 
            ), 
            (int) 0 => array( 
                            'date_part' => '3',
                            'jumlah' => null, 
                            'jumbuy' => '65000', 
                            'admin' => '5000' 
            ),
            (int) 1 => array( 
                                'date_part' => '4',
                                'jumlah' => null, 
                                'jumbuy' => '9000', 
                                'admin' => '5000' 
            )
),
(int) 3 => array(
            'B' => array(
                        'company' => 'CDE'
            ), 
            'User' => array( 
                            'company' => 'cde' 
            ), 
            (int) 0 => array(
                            'date_part' => '4',
                            'jumlah' => null, 
                            'jumbuy' => '34566', 
                            'admin' => '2010' 
            )
)
);
```

**Get Index**

```
for ($row = 0; $row < count($array); $row++) {
    for($col = 0; $col < count(.....); $col++ ) {
       echo "Baris [row] kolom [colum]"; // output row and column
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use foreach loop.

Comment: @chandresh_cool's can you tell me?

Answer (score 3):

The below code will give you all the indexes of this given array.

I checked the given array with the following code in my localhost.

And it gives us all the keys and the values in this array.

Try this

```
<?php
foreach($array as $arr=>$value ) 
{
  foreach($value as $ar=>$a)
  {
    echo $ar."<br>"; 
    foreach($a as $res =>$r)
    {
        echo $res.": ";
        echo $r;
        echo "<br>";
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: how about using the statement for

Comment: With `for` loop, It is hard to get the array keys that's why we use `foreach` loop instead of `for`.

Comment: As for as I know, Using `for` loop, you can get the key and values from single dimensional array. It is hard to get key and values of a multi-dimensional array using `for` loop. So we prefer `foreach` loop.

Comment: #gunaseelan I have seen the link , on the web for looping script for rows and columns have been known for rows and columns

Comment: #gunaseelan so if I use a script "for with count". the data will automatically show according to the amount of data

Answer (score 1):

Use nested `foreach` for `echo`es keys:

```
foreach ($array as $row => $v) {
    foreach ($v as $col => $val) {
        echo 'row: ' . $row . ', col: ' . $col . '<br>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use the following

```
foreach ($values as $inde => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $key => $result) {
        echo '['. $inde.'] ---' .$key . '<br>'; 
    }
}
```

output will be

```
[0] ---B
[0] ---User
[0] ---0
[0] ---1
[1] ---B
[1] ---User
[1] ---0
[1] ---1
[3] ---B
[3] ---User
[3] ---0
```

Comment: #jagadeesh's how for value?